# Skype for business's share my screen shows only skype screen and desktop background

Tags: mac-mini, screen-sharing, skype, catalina, beta

Whenever I share my screen using Skype for business(SFB), only SFB's window and mac background image is visible nothing else.

Is it a bug from SFB or Catalina ?

Anyways to resolve this bug ?

P.S

- I recently upgraded my mac os to Catalina beta.
- I downloaded and installed the latest SFB too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to explicitly add permission to share the screen in **System preferences** then SFB shows everything in the screen.

*Ideally SFB should prompt to get some kind of permission to do this or let the user know about this through some message or notification so that it'll be obvious for user.Catlaina is released to public as well so I hope Microsoft address this issue soon*

Please make the below manual choices to get rid of this problem

- System Preferences
- Security and Privacy
- Screen Recording
- Check the Skype for Business option.

[image: SFB]